# How do you negate the following sentence?

Tags: quantifiers

$ ∀x ∈ R,∃n ∈ Z ,x^{n}>0 $

How do you negate it so that the ¬ symbol does not arise to the left of any quantifier?
Is the negated statement is true?

Answer (score 4):

> How do you negate it so that the ¬ symbol does not arise to the left of any quantifier?

Let $P$ be some property on a variable $z .$

Two important hints:

$$ \tag{1}\neg [\forall z,  P(z)] \iff \exists z: \neg P(z)$$

$$ \tag{2} \neg [\exists z : P(z)] \iff \forall z,  \neg  P(z)$$

---

> Is the negated statement true?

Since telling you the negation would be spoiling things for you, note that a statement is true if and only if its negation is false (i.e. precisely one of either a statement or its negation must be true).

The statement you've given is: "Given any real number $x$, there's some integer $n$ such that $x^n$ is positive."

You tell me: for $x=0,$ does there exist such an $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: You tell me: for x=0, does there exist such an n∈ℤ? No, because 0 to any integer will not be greater than 0.

Comment: @DanielGemara Precisely!